# How to modify Accessibility Context of JTextArea

Tags: java, accessibility, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to modify the accessibility of a `JTextArea` (and other Components) to allow screen readers / accessibility programs like **JAWS** and **VoiceOver** (which I believe use javax.accessibility) to read specific content in addition to the text provided. In a specific case, I need the screen reader to read the line number prior to the text when the user moves to a new line. I have a `CaretListener` that checks to see if the user moved to a new line and I'm getting the new line number, however I am unsure how to get accessible programs to read that information.